# Zooming the Bitmap on Surfaceview in Android

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview

I want to resize the bitmap slowly (like zooming in the bitmap )on surface view. When I set some standard increased values for width and height, it will displays the bigger image.As I give below in onDraw method

```
can.drawBitmap(gball, lastVisitedX, lastVisitedY, paint);
                gball = getResizedBitmap(gball, bitmapInitHeight
                        + bitmapInitHeight, bitmapInitHeight + bitmapInitHeight);


public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,
                matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;

    }
```

But when I try to resize by increasing the height and width like

```
can.drawBitmap(gball, lastVisitedX, lastVisitedY, paint);
                gball = getResizedBitmap(gball, bitmapInitHeight
                        + zoomXValue, bitmapInitHeight + zoomYValue);

zoomXValue= zoomXValue+5;
zoomYValue= zoomYValue+5;
```

In onDraw method but the bitmap is resize with bad quality.

Finally my question is how to scale like zooming out with out damaging the quality.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you want to zoom images, I suggest you this library: https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom

Answer (score 0):

You are always going to have scaling problems especially if you scale up and you have same hard edges on your image, only way you can avoid this (in some manner) is to use larger image and always scale down (Still not going to help with hard edges). 
Try setting Filter to true it might help a little :)

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I just want to resize the Bitmap slowly, when I try to do the bitmap is totally changed. And I already set the properties like filters.